# Mathematica thinks (-1)^n is non-real

Tags: numerics, summation

When I ask Mathematica to evaluate

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}]
```

it returns -0.688172 + 2.11297*10^-16 i

Why is this? (-1)^n is either 1 or -1. I don't know why it is returning a non-real number. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: wyas to avoid: `NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]` or `N@Sum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}]`

Comment: For this sum one can do also `N@Sum` or `Chop@NSum`.

Comment: @corey979 Interesting. What is the difference between NSum and N@Sum?

Comment: `Sum` gives an exact result (check it), to which you then apply `N`. And I guess `NSum` treats every component with machine precision, so there are more opportunities to introduce rounding errors. Interestingly, however, `Sum[N@....]` and `NSum[((-1.)....` give correct results. So `NSum` must have a different implementation.

Comment: Expecting exact results from approximate numeric calculations is a recipe for disappointment.

Comment: IIRC, there's another function which is like sum, except it has the effect of "do the calculation directly" rather than "use various methods to determine the result". I don't recall the name, though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Machine floating point arithmetic can produce strange results when the numbers get very small. Here are same ways to deal with it.

Suppress insignificant imaginary parts.

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}] // Chop
```

> `-0.688172`

Work with exact numbers until the very end (slower).

```
Sum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}] // N
```

> `-0.688172`

Use Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic rather than machine arithmetic.

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

> `-0.688172179310`

Use the special method that `NSum` has for maintaining precision with series that have terms with alternating signs. This is likely to be the best solution for this particular sum.

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]
```

> `-0.688172`

Answer (score 14):

`NSum` uses a combination of analytic and numeric methods.  For instance, it computes

```
(-1)^102.
(*  1. - 1.95968*10^-14 I  *)
```

with a real exponent instead of an exact integer.  It's the same as `Exp[102. Log[-1]]`, which is the same as `Exp[I * 102. * Pi]`, for that is how `Power` is computed when the exponent is `Real`.  Rounding error in `102. * Pi` introduces a small, complex part in the final result.

For more, see the output of

```
Trace[NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}]]
```

As [@kglr pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/mathematica-thinks-1n-is-non-real#comment439918_166566), the way to make *Mathematica* handle the `-1` power appropriately is with

```
NSum[((-1)^n)/n, {n, 1, 100}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]
```

The fact that `Power` with a negative base is going to be a complex-valued function when the exponent is an approximate `Real` can be countered, given the terms are real, by using `Re`:

```
NSum[Re[((-1)^n)/n], {n, 1, 100}]
(*  -0.688172  *)
```

A different approach that uses exact exponents and `Real` base:

```
Total[(-1.)^#/# &@Range[100]]
(*  -0.688172  *)
```

Integer powers are treated differently than floating-point powers.  `Total` tends to be a better way to approach small finite sums.

Comment: I think Mathematica floating point handling sometimes can be strange. I tried all these commands shown in the question and answers given, in Maple 2017. used Maple floating points (evalf) (not hardware floating points evalfh) and never got a complex value to show up. I think one needs a PhD in computer science to really understand Mathematica's floating points handling :)

Comment: @Nasser Did you try `exp(102*log(-1))` in Maple? In Matlab, `exp(..)` gives the *Mathematica* result, but `(-1).^102` gives `1`. I think in Matlab and maybe Maple, `-1` raised to a floating-point whole number is treated as a special case. OTOH, `(-1)^10000000000000001` in Matlab yields `1`. -- I rather think in this case, Mathematica's handling is predictably consistent and normal: `a^b == Exp[b * Log[a]]` and `Log[-1] = Pi * I`. One should expect a rounding error of at most `102*Pi*$MachineEpsilon/2`, which is about what we get. IMO, the issue not floating point, but the def. of `(-1)^x`.

Comment: For `exp(102*log(-1))` Maple gives `1` here is screen shot   ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0lTdc.png)

Comment: @Nasser I see an imaginary part on the order of `10^-8` on the floating-point input; that seems like a large error. Does Maple use single-precision? I mean *Mathematica* gives `1`, too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IoQZv.png

Comment: By default, Maple software floating points uses the `Digits` setting. By default this is set to `10`. Here is the same thing, when I changed it to `16` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IgM0z.png)   Maple software floating point is what used by default. Now it give similar value as Mathematica. To use hardware floating point, there is `evalfh` also.

Answer (score 8):

I want to mention that this sum has a closed form in terms of Mathematica functions

```
(-1)^n*LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n] - Log[2]
```

As already carefully pointed out by Michael, the `(-1)^n` part introduces the small imaginary parts when you apply it to real values. If you are interested in a approximate result, the easiest way is to calculate the above term for integers and *then* taking `N`.

```
f[n_Integer] := N[(-1)^n*LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n] - Log[2]]

f[100]
(* -0.688172 *)
```

However, calculating `LerchPhi` should be faster when calculated with approximate numbers in the first place. So the other solution is to put the `N` inside `LerchPhi`. Therefore, the better alternative if you want to calculate this for large `n` might be this

```
f2[n_Integer] := (-1)^n*LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + N[n]] - Log[2]
```

A quick comparison shows, that I can easily calculate `2^20` in half a second

```
f2[2^20] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.508786, -0.693147} *)
```

while the exact computation of `f` needs about 300x the time of this

```
f[2^20] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {147.191, -0.693147} *)
```

Runtime-wise, nothing will beat `NSum` if it implicitly contains a more expensive function. Therefore, my last point is to mention that you can easily split your sum into to parts: All positive terms and all negative terms. With this, you get completely rid of the `(-1)^n` term and no `Chop` is necessary

```
nn = 100;
NSum[1/n, {n, 2, nn, 2}] - NSum[1/n, {n, 1, nn - 1, 2}]
(* -0.688172 *)
```

Comment: Grouping all the positive terms and then all the negatives is going to have a deleterious effect on the resulting precision.  Much better would be to pair terms `1/n - 1/(n+1)` and simplify to `1/n/(n+1)`, and best to sort from smallest to largest (here that means iterate `n` in decreasing order)

Comment: @BenVoigt I see your point but have you actually verified this? In this scenario the values of the separate sums are just too different to introduce a large cancellation of digits. This means, that comparing your sum with the separate sum, only the last 3 binary digits are different and 50 binary digits are equal. Nevertheless, your idea of putting two terms together to get rid of the `(-1)^n` term is very valuable.

Comment: In addition, calculating your terms and adding them in reverse order gives a result that differs only in the last digit from the exact value (machine precision).

Comment: Certainly the magnitude of the improvement will vary depending on how quickly the sequence decays.  It could well be only affect the final 3 bits in this case.  BTW was that from summing `(1/n) - (1/(n+1))` or `1/n/(n+1)` ?